# How to install Date Picker form control in Excel 2016

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I use Excel from Office 365 and want to use date picker form. Unfortunately, it is not listed in the list of additional controls (More Controls). How to include it into spreadsheet that I am developing? Is there  something that I need to download and install?

Comment: Google this and download: MSCOMCT2.OCX

Comment: I won't put the steps out as an answer. This video explains everything you need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtRQC5qnrHQ&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckOzn3l2_VWUicXZvywNSI4&index=18

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make the assumption you're using [this](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/datepicker.htm) add-in.
If that's the case, the installation is fairly easy. It depends on what OS you're using, though.

Here's what the website states:

> **1)** Download the RDB Date Picker add-in.
>   **2)** Copy WinDatePicker.xlam to a unprotected directory on your system.
>   **3)** Start Excel and open a workbook.
>   *2007: Click the Microsoft Office Button, click Excel Options, click the Add-Ins tab.
>
>   2010-2016: Click on File, click on Options, click the Add-ins tab.*
>   In the Manage drop-down, choose Excel Add-ins, and click Go. Use "Browse" to select the add-in and then click on OK. Verify that the Date Picker is checked in the add-in list and then click OK.
>   **4)** Right click on a worksheet cell and choose Date Picker to open the user form.

That should work, if not, please tell me. Also, tell me if you used another date picker.

Comment: I wanted to use Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control thinking that this would be the easies option to install on my PC and on PCs of users of my application. Unfortunately, Excel does not give me such option.

Comment: I managed to install Microsoft one.
There is just one issue - I dream of a date picker that would be portable i.e. can be embed into Excel file and work on any PC under Windows 32 or 64 without prior installation (Office 32 only would be acceptable). Is there

Comment: MarcoMarc: your video is great. The only issue might be portability from PC to PC...